# How to get the aws s3 objects metadata from java sdk based on Last modified time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I need to fetch the object metadata based on the last modified time from Java SDK

I can fetch the data based on last modified time from AWS CLI but I need the same thing from java SDK

I used the following command to get the data

```
s3api list-objects --bucket aws-codestar-us-east-2-148844964152052  --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2020-02-28T09:34:50+00:00'].{Key: Key, Size: Size,LastModified:LastModified}"
```

**response is:**

```
[
{
    "Key": "abc.png",
    "Size": 361211,
    "LastModified": "2020-03-04T12:11:14+00:00"
},
{
    "Key": "btest.png",
    "Size": 513624,
    "LastModified": "2020-02-28T09:34:50+00:00"
}
```

]

I am expecting the same response from AWS s3 SDK

Thanks for your time.